# How can I restore a VirtualBox operating system after a clean install?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, restore

Before I wiped my computer, I was careful to back up my VirtualBox operating system and all of its configuration files which were stored at `~/.VirtualBox`. Now that  I've reinstalled my host OS and copied the files over, the OS doesn't show up when I start VirtualBox. How can I get back up and running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create new virtual machine and when you come up to *"Virtual Hard Disk"* section choose *"Use existing hard disk"* and select backup ***.vdi*** image.

Comment: Awesome, then I can modify the created config file with the values from the existing one as well. Thanks!